# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ]but got: undefined. Nextjs, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm getting this error don't know what I'm missing!

I have three files, HeaderOption.js, HeaderOptions.js, Search.js

Here is the code of HeaderOptions.js

```
import HeaderOption from "./HeaderOption";
import  DotsVerticalIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";

import  MapIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  NewspaperIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  PlayIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  SearchIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  PhotographicIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";

   function HeaderOptions() {
    return (
     <div>
        {/* Left */}
        <div className="flex space-x-6">
            <HeaderOption Icon={SearchIcon} tile="All" Selected /> 
            <HeaderOption Icon={PhotographicIcon} tile="Images" />
            <HeaderOption Icon={PlayIcon} tile="Videos" />
            <HeaderOption Icon={NewspaperIcon}  tile="News" />
            <HeaderOption Icon={MapIcon}  tile="Maps" />
            <HeaderOption Icon={DotsVerticalIcon}   tile="More" />

        </div>


        {/* Right */}
        <div className="flex space-x-4">
            <p className="link">Settings</p>
            <p className="Link">Tools</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default HeaderOptions;
```

HeaderOption.js

```
function HeaderOption({Icon, title, selected}) 
{
    return (
        <div className={`flex`}>
            <Icon className="h-4" />
            <p className="hidden sm:inline-flex">{title}</p>

        </div>
    );
         
} 
  

export default HeaderOption;
```

I am getting the above error I checked twice the imports, help would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't you get stack trace with line?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes there is stack trace

Comment: Call Stack
createFiberFromTypeAndProps
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (28389:0)
createFiberFromElement
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (28415:0)
updateElement
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (14931:0)
updateSlot
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15041:0)
reconcileChildrenArray
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15219:0)
reconcileChildFibers
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15691:0)
reconcileChildren
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19971:0)

Comment: You probably want to use named imports for the `@heroicons/react/outline` components, i.e. `import { MapIcon, PlayIcon, ... } from "@heroicons/react/outline";`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not be totally clear on how ES6 imports work.

```
import foo from 'bar'
```

Assigns the default export of the module 'bar' to foo. If there is no default export, foo will be undefined.

```
import  MapIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  NewspaperIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  PlayIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import  SearchIcon from "@heroicons/react/outline";
```

All of those variables will have the same value, the default export, which in your case is undefined.

Use named exports (with curly braces) and everything should work.

Advice for how to figure this out in the future. I am not sure what you did to 'check the imports,' but just logging or debugging to see the value of those imported variables would have told you exactly what was going on.

Comment: Can you be more specific pertaining to using Named Exports! how can i do exactly?

Comment: How do you export these components?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski export default HeaderOption ;

Comment: You are trying to import everything from the same file but you export only one thing from this file

Comment: @KonradLinkowski please guide me how to do it right way

Comment: You literally have an answer above

Comment: `import {MapIcon} from "@heroicons/react/outline"; That being said, if you want to work as a programmer you need the ability to read docs and Google things. Literally any article on Javascript imports would have answered your question.